# Can I put a metal junction box on the side of a joist and run a cable across the face to the other side?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, junction-box, beam

I would like to install a junction box with two incoming circuits via FMC, one outgoing FMC (clothes dryer) and one outgoing as NM-B (washer).

The junction box should go onto the ceiling of an unfinished basement in a 100 year old home in California (Bay Area).

I would like to install the junction box on one side of the joist, not on its face: The basement is already fairly low and installing the junction box on the face just adds opportunity to bump my head.

There is just one issue: The dryer circuit needs to go up the ceiling on one side of the joist, the washer circuit on the other side. So I need to cross that joist.

Here is a picture taken upwards towards the basement ceiling (Note, I do not show the FMC here)

[image]

Can I install the box where I placed it and run a Romex to the other side of the joist, as shown?

I really want to avoid drilling through the joist because I’m concerned about the integrity of this 100 year old thing.

I know generally Romex can’t be run from joist to joist (and requires a running board) but in this case I would just **cross a single joist from one side to the other**. Of course, I’d use NM clamps to fasten the cable properly.

Comment: Not 100% sure on the cable being exposed—but one could make an argument that the presence of the pipes protects it from damage—but the JB is fine on the side of the joists, assuming you never put a ceiling up here.  I assume you're going to have a bushing in one of the knockouts to get the cable into the box, not coming through the back of the box as shown in the pic.  Is your box big enough for two incoming and two outgoing circuits?  By the calculator I used, you need a 30 cu in box.

Comment: I would get a nail or small screwdriver and start poking the wood by hand.  Those white stains might be a sign of rot, so if sistering or repair is needed, it will good to do before more wiring.  A small hole should not matter that much or you have a bigger problem.

Comment: @crip659 I was afraid the stains draw attention… Im not concerned, it’s bone dry. It’s 100years old and I think there once was water damage. I had it inspected and it did not show up as big concerns. Which leaves me with my question: Can I run Romex from one joist side to the other as shown?

Comment: @Huesmann Thank you, can you elaborate how you arrived at 30cu and which calculator you were using? I arrive at max 24.75cu but I never know how to calculate the right way. Here is my result: https://snipboard.io/fmRwPt.jpg EDIT: Oh I see, my box is only 21cu. Seems I need a bigger one indeed. Can you still check the link if I did the calculation correctly?

Comment: I use the Construction Monkey calculator here: https://www.constructionmonkey.com/calculations/misc/boxfill  You have what looks like a 14g cable (could be 12 for older cable), so I'm assuming the washer circuit is 14g.  You don't say what you're using for the dryer, but I'm assuming at least 8g.  So you'll have 4 14g and 6 8g wires spliced in the box, plus at least a 10g ground.  You don't tell us your wire sizes, so I'm only guessing.

Comment: (If your dryer only requires 30A, then you'd be at 10g instead of 8g.)