# Can I bring a Romex cable from one side of a ceiling joist to the other (in an unfinished basement)?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

I have not found any information and answer on this. My question is, can I bring a Romex cable from one side of a ceiling joist to the other over the joist face? All I can find is related to something that's obvious (the red line denotes Romex cable, the white ones cable staples/clamps):

[image]

This case is clearly not allowed because we are running Romex from joist to joist. A **running board** would be required (see NEC 334.15).

However, what I am asking is the following scenario:

[image]

I have a Romex cable on one side of the joist but need to bring it to the other. I explicitly want to avoid drilling through the joist. And a 1-2" "running board" to cross the joist makes no sense, of course.

I don't think this case is really covered by NEC 334.15 ... which covers the case where a cable is actually ran (as in the first image) ... not just an inch joist crossing.

My actual use case is that I have a junction box mounted on the right side of the joist but the hole into the ceiling for the cable is on the *other side* of the joist. I have asked this as part of [Can I put a metal junction box on the side of a joist and run a cable across the face to the other side?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/276397/can-i-put-a-metal-junction-box-on-the-side-of-a-joist-and-run-a-cable-across-the) but this part of the question was not addressed.

Comment: When you set bizarre pre-conditions such as "*I explicitly want to avoid drilling through the joist.*" you encounter bizarre problems as a result.

Comment: you can do what you want.  the purpose of the running board is to prevent people using the electrical cable as something to support hangers.

Comment: i like the P.S. Knight book for residental electrical - https://www.amazon.ca/Electrical-Code-Simplified-Residential-MultiProvince/dp/0920312721/ref=sr_1_6

Comment: @FreshCodemonger   That will probably be a good book for me, but if OP is in the US(looking for NEC code)  there might be a few differences.

Comment: I can see the need to add a steel cable protection plate there, since the cable is not protected by 1.5 inches of wood.  Right now there is no ceiling to hide it, but there might be one in the future.

Comment: differences are pretty minor CEC vs NEC and there aren't many.  In general if you know one then you could just take a look at the difference here - https://rack-a-tiers.ca/2023/01/21/cec-versus-nec.

Comment: I don’t think avoiding a hole (if possible) is a bizarre pre-condition. To me, NEC334.15 deals with the clothes hanger problem but that’s not really an issue when crossing a single joist. To summarize, seems there is not a clear answer whether it’s allowed or not?

Comment: Does nailing or screwing something to a joist also trigger whatever issue you have with drilling a hole?

Comment: @Huesmann I’d prefer nailing or screwing something rather than drilling a hole.